# Golden vermiculite any good?

Tags: potting-soil

I got this vermiculite for plants and wondering if this is good enough or not.

It's golden in color. Very shiny, like gold.

[image]

Should I use this for succulents? How is this thing going to help the plants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with vermiculite in a succulent soil mix is that it is designed to hold moisture in a medium which is supposed to emphasize sharp drainage. So it will not help succulents at all, in fact in theory quite the contrary. Succulents and cacti are adept at profiting from quick, sudden rains by absorbing moisture quickly and then returning rapidly to a dry state. Vermiculite does not provide that facility.

Comment: So it will help in drainage but at the same time retain water?

Comment: No, it retains water well but does not help with drainage. For drainage you need something like horticultural sharp sand which retains water only on the surface of the grains while holding good air spaces in the potting mix.

Answer (score 2):

Vermiculite is expanded mica , a complex silicate that can contain a variety of elements that give it a variety of colors. So the color has nothing ( or little ) to do with its properties.